# Error: "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name..." in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I try to build microservices with **Spring Boot 3.0.2** and Spring cloud. I try to build one Microservice that connects to a Postgres database running on docker. I get the following errors:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController' defined in file [/Users/.../customer/CustomerController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'customerService' defined in file [/Users/...customer/CustomerService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository' defined in com.ioannispriovolos.customer.CustomerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.ioannispriovolos.customer.Customer

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.ioannispriovolos.customer.Customer

I searched a lot for similar questions in stack overflow but none gave me the solution. I provide the customerController.

```
package com.ioannispriovolos.customer;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")
public record CustomerController (CustomerService customerService){

    @PostMapping
    public void registerCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerRegistrationRequest customerRegistrationRequest) {
        log.info("new customer registration {}", customerRegistrationRequest);
        customerService.registerCustomer(customerRegistrationRequest);
    }
}
```

If you need more code from my side please inform me and I will edit the question.
I provide the Customer class after mentioned in the comments.

```
package com.ioannispriovolos.customer;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "customer_id_sequence",
            sequenceName = "customer_id_sequence"
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "customer_id_sequence"
    )
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
}
```

Comment: provide the code of Customer class

Comment: @kerbermeister Thanks for responding, i edited the post with class you asked me to.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 3?

Comment: Yes, I do, 3.0.2 to be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot JPA module as a part of the Spring Boot 3 release turned to work with Jakarta Persistence API rather than with `javax.persistence.api`. This is the reason why `@EntityScan` does not find the entities.

[Read the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories)

[Jakarta Dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api)

Add that dependency to your pom and change the imports in your entities

Change `import javax.persistence.*;` to `import jakarta.persistence.*;`